# Modifying a tessellation vertex in DirectX Shader

Tags: c++, directx, shader, hlsl

I've followed the tessellation tutorial on Rastertek's website and have managed to get it working.

I'm just wondering if its possible to modify a subdivisions vertex in one of the shader files. 
The result I'm looking for is to divide up a plane into subdivisions and then manipulate the subdivisions to create waves, is that possible or have I completed missed something? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it.

Modifications can be made after the vertex position has been calculated in the domain shader.

:D